# Rails + MongoDB + Create sub columns for any column of Table

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails app, I am trying to implement sub columns for storing values.

For Example :-

> User Model have few fields like first_name, last_name, address

Now, If we further divide the address in multiple attributes but under address attribute.

> Model User : First_name, last_name, address ( street, landmark, city,
>   state, country ) - User can store multiple addresses.

It has to be accessible like -> `user.address[0].street, user.address[0].city` etc.

I am not getting the way to implement it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it is a lot easier with mangoose!

If there maybe only one address and you want to access it as you described,
define address in a mongoose model as an array:

```
address: []
```

and push and object in to `address` array and it would be:

```
address: [
  {
    street: '', 
    landmark: '', 
    city: '', 
    state: '', 
    country: ''
  }
]
```

You can access street like so: `address[0].street`

But if multiple addresses are possible, better create a mangoose Address model and set it as a Schema for `address: [AdressModel.schema]`

and you'll be able to easily access any address by _id

http://mongoosejs.com/